# Wordpress getting posts from category in personal layout

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the posts from evenementen. I only want 4 posts because my layout is a 2x2 column. This column has a special template for the top and bot. I want to show the 4 evenementen in this column but I don't want to change the layout if there are less.

In the PHP file I loop all the posts in evenementen and want to do add these in the specific columns.

PHP FILE

```
<?php 
                $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 0 );

                $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                $count = 0;
                foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
                $count++;
                    if ($count == 1) {
                            $title1 = the_title();
                            $date1 = the_date();
                            $link1 = the_permalink();
                        }
                    elseif ($count == 2) {
                            $title2 = the_title();
                            $date2 = the_date();
                            $link2 = the_permalink();
                        }
                    elseif ($count == 3) {
                            $title3 = the_title();
                            $date3 = the_date();
                            $link3 = the_permalink();
                        }
                    elseif ($count == 4) {
                            $title4 = the_title();
                            $date4 = the_date();
                            $link4 = the_permalink();
                        }
                    else {

                        }           
                endforeach;
                ?>

                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div id="bigone">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <h4 class="push"><?php echo $title1; ?></h4>
                            <div id="one"> <p class="greytext"><?php echo $date1; ?></p></div>
                            <div id="two"> <p class="opmaak"><a href="<?php echo $link1; ?>">Evenementen</a></p></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bigtwo">
                    <div class="evenementenborder">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <h4 class="push"><?php echo $title2; ?></h4>
                                <div id="one"> <p><?php echo $date2; ?></p> </div>
                                <div id="two"> <p class="opmaak"><a href="<?php echo $link2; ?>">Evenementen</a> </p></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="evenementenfooter">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div id="bigone">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <h4 class="push"><?php echo $title3; ?></h4>
                            <div id="one"> <p class="greytext"><?php echo $date3; ?></p></div>
                            <div id="two"> <p><a href="<?php echo $link3; ?>">Evenementen</a></p></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bigtwo">
                    <div class="evenementenborder">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <h4 class="push"><?php echo $title4; ?></h4>
                                <div id="one"> <p class="greytext"><?php echo $date4; ?></p> </div>
                                <div id="two"> <p><a href="<?php echo $link4; ?>">Evenementen</a> </p></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the closest I got so far. But this does not put the text on the proper position and the hyperlink is also in the text.

[Webpage](http://www.stivosina.nl/)

I want to ask you guys: what is the best way to solve this? Or if I made a mistake in the code why it is not on the proper position?

I found out that informatie is directly placed on the page and the echo can't find the information because on that moment it is empty. I don't know how to solve this. Please post if you see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i think its the buffering, Put in the beggining

```
ob_start();
```

And in the end of the document

```
ob_end_flush();
```

And try again.
Check here for documentation about buffering

Comment: I think it has something to do whit the php echo. When i don't add the tekst from wordpress ( put static text ) everything is on possition as it should be. With the wordpress text everything is standing in 1 line.

Comment: I found out that the echo is not getting the message. if i move the foreach down in my code the text is getting put there. so the text isn't getting in the echo.